# MEF ComposeParts. How to handle plugin exceptions

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, exception, plugins, mef

I have searched on the web for a solution, but I didn't find anything.

In my C# application I am using MEF for implementing a plugin pattern. Everything is working fine. However today I have tried to figure out what happens if a Plugin Constructor throws an Exception for some reason.

To load plugins I am using `CompositionContainer.ComposeParts`. If for some reason one of the X plugins throws an exception this method will fail and nothing will be loaded.

Is there a way to just catch the single exception, log it and continue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you're calling `CompositionContainer.ComposeParts(this)`, where `this` has a property similar to this:

```
[ImportMany]
public IPlugin[] Plugins { get; set; }
```

which means that when you call `ComposeParts`, all plugins' constructors will be called. Alternatively, you could take advantage of lazy loading, which will defer the constructor calls to when you actually use a plugin

```
[ImportMany]
public Lazy<IPlugin>[] Plugins { get; set; }
```

Then, if you'd like to initialize all plugins, you could have something like this, which will log exceptions, but won't stop you from loading other plugins:

```
public void InitPlugins()
{
    foreach (Lazy<IPlugin> lazyPlugin in Plugins)
    {
        try
        {
            // Call the plugin's constructor
            var plugin = lazyPlugin.Value;

            // Do any other initialization here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log exception and continue iteration
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer looked good in theory until I attempted it; My error is caused by not providing an equivalent Export that an Import expects; I had multiple Imports in my `this` class; I don't believe deferring the constructor errors would help in this case - ComposeParts() fails in an "all or nothing" way (i.e. it does not continue to compose the good import/export pairs, it fails on all if there is a problem with one import/export pair !

Answer (score 0):

I found that switching from ImportMany to Import and then basically creating a CompositionContainer + DirectoryCatalog for each Dll allowed me to easily detect and filter out incompatible plugins.

It was also not noticably slower than calling compose on multiple catalogs at once.