# Avoiding errors when loading DLLs

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, error-handling, mef

I am trying to use MEF, however, I noticed that it will crash if a .dll with the wrong interface is present in the directory that is being currently used. Is there any way to correct/avoid this issue, beyond simply only allowing the correct .dlls to be present in the plugin folder?

**EDIT**

Error is:
`Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`

Comment: What would you like to happen if a required assembly is missing? How is it possible that a "wrong" assembly ends up in your application directory? Is there a "correct" assembly next to it? It seems like you have a different problem, namely a nonfunctional release flow or a documentation issue.

Comment: Really, I am just trying to guard against this issue. If only the correct dlls are present then everything works fine, but it'd be nice to have some way to prevent everything crashing due to someone putting a dll in the wrong spot.

Comment: Can you, for those of us who don't have the exact issue at the top of their mind, include the error you get from MEF when multiple assemblies containing a certain interface exist?

Comment: Yes, there is a "correct" assembly. The error happens when there is any wrong assembly near the correct ones.

Comment: Manually load the correct assembly using the full path first, any lookups should use the loaded one after that instead of loading a new copy.

Comment: @MKII Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25168257/389966